# Enhance recollection abilites

Tags: memory, long-term-memory, working-memory, short-term-memory

I hope this is a good way of asking this question.

I am not generally the guy with the best memory out there, so I looked a bit into it and I am concluding my recollection phase is the weakest. It's seems like I can store a lot but recalling it, I would come under average.

It's not like it has stopped me from doing fine in life, but I am curious about how one can enhance that part, any good reads should you recommend from the scientific literature ?

Thanks.

***Augmented :***

Well I do recall a lot because I can gather a lot from my memory, but then I stumble often in just getting the first starting point from which I would be able to gather all those memories, i.e : I can remember profusely given someone or something helps me with recalling just a part or the beginning of it. So my recalling issue is really in having a sort of catalogue or dictionary like system : once you get the word you get its definition, my trouble is in getting the word (I hope the analogy is clear). Working memory is short-term memory? Can be, what are symptoms for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practice or forget, that is the rule. If you want to recall more words for your vocabulary then read more and write more texts with less common words. If you want to recall memories look at old photographs of your life and try to recall everything associated with those events.
Memory improves when health improves, so work on that too.

Comment: Please visit our site [tour]. There are a lot of bold claims in your answer without corroborated evidence. We work differently to many SE sites, where we have a strict policy that [all answers should be backed up with reliable references](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/406/7604) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's/answerer's background. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can be challenged and lead to deletion of your answer.